# Passing multiple arguments to a function to check duplicate values from an array

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to count duplicate values from a column range using an array, I created a function that takes 3 arguments, number of rows and 2 strings (Long,String,String) for the comparison. I noticed that it only detects duplicates whenever values are next to each other. I already tried looping from 1 to the last row to make sure that each value will be compared to the rest but I got subscript out of range error.

Here's my code:

```
Sub CountByErrorTest()

Dim rangeArr() As Variant
Dim tester2 As Worksheet
Set tester2 = Worksheets("tester2")
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lrow As Long
lrow = 3169
rangeArr = Worksheets("tester").Range("a2").Resize(lrow, 29).Value2

For i = 1 To 29      
    For j = 1 To lrow - 1
        If dupVal((rangeArr(j, i)), ((rangeArr(j + 1, i)))) Then
            tester2.Range("g4") = tester2.Range("g4") + 1
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

My function:

```
Function dupVal(s1 As String, s2 As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
        If s1 = s2 Then
            dupVal = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    dupVal = False
End Function
```

I tried looping it like this: Gets out of range error

```
  For k = 1 To lrow - 1
      If dupVal((rangeArr(j, i)), ((rangeArr(j + k, i)))) Then
          tester2.Range("g4") = tester2.Range("g4") + 1
      End If
  Next k
```

I would appreciate suggestions to make it better or if there's an easier way to do it that would be really nice.

Comment: Side note... `For i = 1 To rlen` - this is unnecessary. That means you are comparing `s1 to s2` multiple times. That's a comparison that only should happen *once*, no loop required.

Comment: Could we define the number of duplicates like this: `AllValues.Count - UniqueValues.Count`? If so using a dictionary should be more efficient.

Comment: @BigBen I missed that. Means I only need to pass 2 strings. Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered what to do about `empty`, `blank` and `error` values? And will the comparison be case-sensitive i.e. `A<>a`?

Comment: I already took care of the empty and blanks. Error values most likely won't happen in this case. Not necessarily case sensitive i.e. test = TesT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The duplicates are only being counted when they are next to each other because of this:

```vb
dupVal((rangeArr(j, i)), ((rangeArr(j + 1, i))))
```

The function goes through the entire range and literally compares each column to that column + 1. So, if there was a duplicate 2 or more columns ago, or 1 or more rows ago, the function would not detect it.

The simplest way to detect duplicates is to build a unique list of the values you do know about. Then, when you encounter a new value as you loop through the range, you compare it to that list (which in this case, is an array). If you find it in the list, you count it as a duplicate, because you've seen it before. Otherwise, it's a new value, so add it to the list. In code, this would be:

```vb
Function CountByErrorTest() As Long
    Const lcol As Long = 29
    Const lrow As Long = 3169
    
    Dim uniqueArr() As Variant, find As Variant
    Dim tester1 As Worksheet, tester2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, count As Long, uniqueU As Long
    Dim found As Boolean
    
    Set tester1 = Worksheets("tester")
    Set tester2 = Worksheets("tester2")
    
    uniqueU = -1
    count = 0
    
    ReDim uniqueArr(0)
    uniqueArr(0) = Null
    
    'Loop through columns
    For i = 1 To lcol
        'Loop through rows
        For j = 1 To lrow
            find = tester1.Cells(j, i).Value
            found = False
            
            'Loop through array of unique values
            For k = LBound(uniqueArr) To UBound(uniqueArr)
                'Check whether this is a known value
                If (find = uniqueArr(k)) Then
                    found = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next k
            
            If found = True Then
                'Count the duplicate
                count = count + 1
            Else
                'Add new value to the array
                uniqueU = uniqueU + 1
                ReDim Preserve uniqueArr(uniqueU)
                uniqueArr(uniqueU) = find
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    tester2.Range("g4").Value = count

    CountByErrorTest = count
End Function
```

If you get to a point where you need to do something like this for a very large range, it may start to get slow. To make it more faster, there are data structures which can be used to more efficiently store and retrieve the unique values as you're checking through the range. Using a [binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) instead of an array would be an example of this.

EDIT: Here's an example of how you can generalise this function to accept a range as a parameter and call it from elsewhere:

```vb
Function CountByErrorTest(ByRef tester1 As Worksheet, ByRef tester2 As Worksheet, ByRef range As range) As Long
    Dim uniqueArr() As Variant, find As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, count As Long, uniqueU As Long, lcols As Long, lrows As Long
    Dim found As Boolean
    
    lcols = range.Column + range.Columns.count - 1
    lrows = range.Row + range.Rows.count - 1
    
    uniqueU = -1
    count = 0
    
    ReDim uniqueArr(0)
    uniqueArr(0) = Null
    
    'Loop through columns
    For i = range.Column To lcols
        'Loop through rows
        For j = range.Row To lrows
            find = tester1.Cells(j, i).Value
            found = False
            
            'Loop through array of unique values
            For k = LBound(uniqueArr) To UBound(uniqueArr)
                'Check whether this is a known value
                If (find = uniqueArr(k)) Then
                    found = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next k
            
            If found = True Then
                'Count the duplicate
                count = count + 1
            Else
                'Add new value to the array
                uniqueU = uniqueU + 1
                ReDim Preserve uniqueArr(uniqueU)
                uniqueArr(uniqueU) = find
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    CountByErrorTest = count
End Function

Sub ExampleCallFunction()
    Dim tester1 As Worksheet, tester2 As Worksheet
    Dim range As range

    Set tester1 = Worksheets("tester")
    Set tester2 = Worksheets("tester2")
    
    Set range = tester2.range("b4:c5") 'set what your range is here
    
    tester2.range("g4").Value = CountByErrorTest(tester1, tester2, range)
End Sub
```

Comment: Let me check this out. Thanks for your suggestion. This looks really neat. Would this perform well in 10k-Rows by 30-Cols range?

Comment: Try it out and see - it may depend on your PC performance, how often you are going to run it and how long you consider acceptable to wait. If you want to improve performance, the main optimisation you could make from there is the one I mentioned. It also depends on what's in your range - for example, if you expect there to be many blanks, you could optimise by ignoring those.

Comment: I don't know why it always lacks 1 count, so I end up `tester2.range("g4").value = count+1`

Comment: Which part should I change if I want it to trigger the count every time it finds a non-unique value?

Comment: I've found and fixed a minor bug that should resolve both of these issues - `ReDim uniqueArr(uniqueU)` should have been `ReDim Preserve uniqueArr(uniqueU)`. If you try again with the edited code it should work fine now :)

Comment: Yeah it worked. I need two more things I hope you can help me: First,  how would I turn this into a boolean type function, so I can just call it every time I need it; Second, the duplicate counter should trigger every time it sees duplicate not just once i.e. if it sees "test","test","test" duplicate count = 2.

Comment: I solved the duplicate count. Now my last problem is how to make this a FUNCTION. I'm not sure what are the parameter types to use. I'm also thinking instead of a BOOLEAN type function I'll make it a LONG type so it will simply return the duplicate count but I am not sure if I should go for an ARRAY or just the RANGE parameter. Any thoughts? @sbgib

Comment: I've checked the count it returns and it seems correct to me - the only thing to be aware of there, as far as I can tell, is that it is counting blank cells too. Watch out for different data types (e.g. 0 and "0"). I've updated the sub to be a function which returns the count, so you can call the function, get the count back and use that in whatever boolean you might need (e.g. `0 < count`). The parameters you specify will be the ones that you might wish to change (e.g. `lCol`, `lRow`, worksheet names, include blanks, etc.)

Comment: This is how I constructed the function parameters `Function CountByErrorTest(arrRange As Range, row As Long, col As Long) As Long`. This is how I called it `tester2.Range("g4").Value = CountByErrorTest(tester1.Range("a2:a" & lrow), lrow, i)` but I got type mismatch error in this line `If Not IsEmpty(find) And (find = uniqueArr(u)) Then`. My wild guess is because of this line `find = arrRange.Value`. @sbgib

Comment: Should I do it like `find = arrRange.Cells(lrow, lcol).Value`?

Comment: If you want the function to accept a range as an input, then you also have to change how the function works so that it knows what to do with that range. I've added an example to the answer so you can see a way to do this.